Aggregate (sum) consecutive rows where the number of consecutive rows is defined in a dataframe column
Initial Dataframe:
Every "id" has the same "range" value, I have to execute the following aggregation:

grouping on column "id" a dynamic range of consecutive rows (col "range")
sum the column "amount" for that range of consecutive rows
ordering based on "id","row_num" asc




id
row_num
range
amount




a
1
2
2


a
2
2
10


a
3
2
5


a
4
2
5


a
5
2
1


b
1
3
10


b
2
3
2


b
3
3
10


b
4
3
6


b
5
3
10


b
6
3
4



target result:



id
row_num
range
amount
sum




a
1
2
2
12


a
2
2
10
15


a
3
2
5
10


a
4
2
5
6


a
5
2
1
1


b
1
3
10
22


b
2
3
2
18


b
3
3
10
26


b
4
3
6
20


b
5
3
10
14


b
6
3
4
4



I've tried with Window.rowsBetween but cannot use the "range" column  value dynamically.
I don't want to use "case...when" or "hardcoded like" syntax as the sample Dataframe is a simplified version of the real one.
I'm pretty sure it can be solved with "advanced" windowing / partitioning.
Any tips?

You can use Pyspark's Windows functions. Especially rowsBetween. Look it up. This should be easy peasy.

@user238607 I've already tried but rowsBetween does not accect a dataframe column as argument; since there can be any range value per id, rowsBetween should be dynamic, not static.

One possible approach is to collect the amounts per id, then slice them based on ('row_num', 'range') and then sum:
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T
from pyspark.sql import Window

data = [
    ('a', 1, 2, 2),
    ('a', 2, 2, 10),
    ('a', 3, 2, 5),
    ('a', 4, 2, 5),
    ('a', 5, 2, 1),
    ('b', 1, 3, 10),
    ('b', 2, 3, 2),
    ('b', 3, 3, 10),
    ('b', 4, 3, 6),
    ('b', 5, 3, 10),
    ('b', 6, 3, 4)
]

schema = T.StructType([
    T.StructField('id', T.StringType(), True),
    T.StructField('row_num', T.IntegerType(), True),
    T.StructField('range', T.IntegerType(), True),
    T.StructField('amount', T.IntegerType(), True)
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

w = (
    Window
    .partitionBy('id')
    .orderBy('row_num')
    .rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
)
amounts = F.collect_list('amount').over(w)
row_amounts = F.slice(amounts, start='row_num', length='range')
sum_amounts = F.aggregate(
    col=row_amounts,
    initialValue=F.lit(0),
    merge=lambda x, y: x + y
)
df = df.withColumn('sum', sum_amounts)
df.show(20, False)

# +---+-------+-----+------+---+
# |id |row_num|range|amount|sum|
# +---+-------+-----+------+---+
# |a  |1      |2    |2     |12 |
# |a  |2      |2    |10    |15 |
# |a  |3      |2    |5     |10 |
# |a  |4      |2    |5     |6  |
# |a  |5      |2    |1     |1  |
# |b  |1      |3    |10    |22 |
# |b  |2      |3    |2     |18 |
# |b  |3      |3    |10    |26 |
# |b  |4      |3    |6     |20 |
# |b  |5      |3    |10    |14 |
# |b  |6      |3    |4     |4  |
# +---+-------+-----+------+---+


This is quick fix for the problem. First we find unique values of the id and range pair. Since id and range are guaranteed to have same value.
Next step is to iterate over the list of unique values. In the forloop, we filter the dataframe, partition it, order by row_num and sum with rowsBetween.
This works because values for range is known at this stage. It is not dynamic anymore.
Finally, we union all the dataframes.
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("MyApp") \
    .getOrCreate()


# Define the data
data = [
    ('a', 1, 2, 2),
    ('a', 2, 2, 10),
    ('a', 3, 2, 5),
    ('a', 4, 2, 5),
    ('a', 5, 2, 1),
    ('b', 1, 3, 10),
    ('b', 2, 3, 2),
    ('b', 3, 3, 10),
    ('b', 4, 3, 6),
    ('b', 5, 3, 10),
    ('b', 6, 3, 4)
]

schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("row_num", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("range", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("amount", IntegerType(), True)
])


df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
df.show()

unique_values = df.select("id", "range").drop_duplicates()
unique_values.show()

unique_values_list = unique_values.rdd.collect()

list_of_result_dfs = []

for list_element in unique_values_list:
    id_value = list_element["id"]
    range_value = list_element["range"]
    print(id_value, range_value)
    filtered_df = df.filter((F.col("range") == range_value) & (F.col("id") == id_value))
    windowSpec = Window.partitionBy(F.lit(id_value)).orderBy("row_num").rowsBetween(0, range_value - 1)
    filtered_df = filtered_df.withColumn("sum", F.sum(F.col("amount")).over(windowSpec))
    filtered_df.show()
    count_my = filtered_df.cache().count()
    print(f"{count_my=}")
    list_of_result_dfs.append(filtered_df)


from functools import reduce, partial
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

# Union dataframes by name (missing columns filled with null)
union_by_name = partial(DataFrame.unionByName, allowMissingColumns=True)
df_output = reduce(union_by_name, list_of_result_dfs)

print("Final Output")
df_output.show()

Output :
Final Output
+---+-------+-----+------+---+
| id|row_num|range|amount|sum|
+---+-------+-----+------+---+
|  a|      1|    2|     2| 12|
|  a|      2|    2|    10| 15|
|  a|      3|    2|     5| 10|
|  a|      4|    2|     5|  6|
|  a|      5|    2|     1|  1|
|  b|      1|    3|    10| 22|
|  b|      2|    3|     2| 18|
|  b|      3|    3|    10| 26|
|  b|      4|    3|     6| 20|
|  b|      5|    3|    10| 14|
|  b|      6|    3|     4|  4|
+---+-------+-----+------+---+


the result is correct but I wanted to use partitioning / windowing methods only (or other spark based functions) levering distributed computing instead of loop iterations / for cycles for performance matter; I'll use the solution you propesed for now though, thanks!

You can use hashpartitioning and then mapPartition on the partitions created.
